# How to create a flyout which appears from right side of screen on image tap event?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am working on Windows Store App which requires to provide some filter options to user when he taps on filter icon. I am aware how to use flyouts but I am stucked on how to meet my requirement. Please suggest. I want to do something similar like shown in below images

[image: Filter icon]

When user clicks on filter,flyout must open from right side of the screen similar to below image.

[image: Filter options]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like Nasser said to you, by adding some storyboard to a grid via Blend, or by adding a custom SettingFlyout as this sample shows how to do it  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49

Comment: Thanks Riadh, will check this, but I have one doubt when I click on app settings will it open the same custom flyout which I have created for filter options?

Comment: Yes it will be opened after some choices, you can also open your custom layout after a button click or an event_hanldler. Look at the sample and you can find all possible  scenarios. I hope that the sample was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Riadh for your resposne. Also can you suggest how to animated a control for eg: when i click on + , a drop down will open with radio button in that region and (+ will change to -) and then when I click - the region should hide but value should be selected unless he presses RESET button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in XAML, Just right the Main XAML code then write the Right Grid and do some Storyboard by Blend :) .

```
<Grid>
        <!-- Your main xaml code.. -->
            <!-- right side menu -->
        <Grid Width="400"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="400"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <!-- some filters -->
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

**UPDATE :**

Ref : [Storyboard for XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Nasser. But I have never used StoryBoard till now. Can you share some useful links ? It would be great help

Comment: Can you add StoryBoard in the answer code given by you ?